# Exclude @Configuration annotated class from getting created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project, with a dependency(another spring-boot project) with an implementation like this.

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UtilityConfiguration{
  private final ProducerFactory producerFactory;
   
   @Bean
   public KafkaProducer<K, V> getProducers(){
       return producerFactory.getProducers();
   }

}
```

The getProducers method reads the kafka configuration and does
`new KafkaProducer<>(producerProperties)`

Context of project and problem.
The above piece of code is from an utility, which also has few other things which is of the only interest in the spring boot project, and not the kafka implementation.
However, when I start the spring boot project, this producer automatically gets initialized and fails with authentication error.

I searched in SO and found that there is an exlude filter option which can be used with component scan
Eg -
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.basepackage", excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = UtilityConfiguration.class))`
But, these aren't helping.
Is there a way for me to exlcude this bean from getting created at all, THAT TOO REFERRED FROM AN UTILITY?
Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Spring version - 2.3.1.RELEASE
kafka - org.apache.kafka 2.5.0

Comment: `@ConditionalOnXXX`

Comment: @Eugene It looks like I have to go and add this Conditional annotation on the utility. But, issue is I don't have control over the utility and its actually used across  multiple clients. So introducing this change requires clients to update this, which is a concern. Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={UtilityConfiguration.class})` on top of your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class as referred in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.12.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html).

If the `UtilityConfiguration.class` is not in your classpath, you can use FQN (full qualified name) of the class.

Additionally, you can use `application.properties` or `applycation.yml` to exclude class:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude
```